# I am looking for the code to successfully store the information read from my input file into an ArrayList in Java

Tags: java

This is what I have tried so far... I have a method inside of this package in a separate class called loadData(String) that loads the data inside an input file. However this use of the loadData method gives an error saying this type is undefined for LibraryApplication.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class LibraryApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
            try {
                Scanner x = new Scanner(new File("BookCatalog.txt"));
                ArrayList<Book> booklist = new ArrayList<Book>();
                loadData()
            } 
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }    
        }    
    }

    public void loadData(String filename) {

        this.filename = filename;

        Scanner reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new Scanner(new File(filename));
            Book book = null;

            while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
                book = new Book(reader.nextLine(), reader.nextLine(), reader.nextLine(), reader.nextLine(),
                        Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine()));
                reader.next();
                booklist.add(book);
            }
            booklist.sort(null);
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.print("Error: Unable to load file. ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please provide the `loadData()` method. it doesn't appear that you are operating on your Scanner x at all

Comment: What is the separate class that contains `loadData`? Is `loadData` a `static` method?

Comment: You say it's loaddata(String), I assume the input param is a file name? You did not pass in a string into the method of the above calling code. Example) loadData("BookCatalog.txt");

Comment: I will add the loadData method

Comment: @ElliottFrisch The loadData method is not a static method.

Answer (score 0):

Class LibraryApplication has no method named loadData(). You probably need to implement it.

Furthermore, your loadData -- where is it going to get the data, and where is it going to put it?

Let's say you have this:

```
public class Loader {
    public void loadData(Scanner x, ArrayList<Book> books) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then in main, you need to do:

```
Loader loader;
loader.loadData(s, booklist);
```

Comment: I have added the loadData() method. Please take a look at my code again and then explain why I am not able to access the method. The loadData method is still apart of a different class inside of the package.

Comment: Your loadData method you're now including takes arguments. You're not passing arguments.

Comment: The edited version of the code passes "BookCatalog.txt"